# H2o Driverless-AI cannot import data

Tags: h2o, driverless-ai

I tried to import my data in json format but it took forever to import and I cannot do anything except waiting.

The files consist of a list of images, and for each image, you can find the following fields:
id - the id of the image
band_1, band_2 - the flattened image data. Each band has 75x75 pixel values in the list, so the list has 5625 elements. Note that these values are not the normal non-negative integers in image files since they have physical meanings - these are float numbers with unit being dB. Band 1 and Band 2 are signals characterized by radar backscatter produced from different polarizations at a particular incidence angle. 
inc_angle - the incidence angle of which the image was taken. Note that this field has missing data marked as "na", and those images with "na" incidence angles are all in the training data to prevent leakage.
is_iceberg - the target variable, set to 1 if it is an iceberg, and 0 if it is a ship.

Please advise what I can do to try this product on my data. I want to predicted probability that this image is iceberg.

Comment: Have you tried converting the file to CSV format?

Comment: Yes, I converted and can process on CSV now. Tks !

Answer (score 0):

reposting branden murray's solution: you can convert your json to csv.

also here are the currently support file formats for driverless as of version 1.1.6 (May 29 2018)

File formats supported:

- Plain text formats of columnar data (.csv, .tsv, .txt)

  Compressed archives (.zip, .gz)

  Excel files

  Feather binary files

  Python datatable binary directories